# Alternative to Nicehash Miner for Linux

Tags: miner-configuration, linux, nicehash

I have a high performance Desktop computer with a powerful NVIDIA GPU available.
I wonder if there is some software similar to NiceHash Miner which I can install in Linux to make some little cash while I'm working on the machine doing other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many blog posts, howtos, etc. available through Google which will tell you know to *mine* your favourite crypto currency using an NVIDIA GPU on Linux.

Please note that NiceHash is something similar but different. NiceHash is an online marketplace for hashing capacity. It is *not* a mining pool. NishHash is about renting out hashing capacity to people who think they know how to get back more rewards from using X amout of hash than they have to pay for it.

AFAIK NiceHash does not offer a Linux client. Did you try to run it in a VM or on Wine?

Comment: @TorsenS Actually it did not work with wine. But I managed to start mining with ethminer in another pool.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is outdated, but in case anyone is still interested in this question, there are some that can be found [here](https://bitcoinminingsoftware2019.com/alternative-to-nicehash/)(Linux ones are at the bottom).

To sum it up for you, there are two GUI alternatives for Nicehash on Linux- Cudo Miner and MinerGate.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, sorry I'm still new here. Hope the updated answer helps.